# Special linear group of degree 2

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ which is closed in the $p$-adic topology.

For each $n > 0$ , denote by $G_n$ the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{GL_2}(\mathbb Z/p^n \mathbb Z)$.

Suppose that $G_1$ contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ and
$G_n$ contains the kernel of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z) \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z/p^{n-1}\Bbb Z)$ for each $n>1$.

Then $G_n$ contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z)$ for each $n>1$.

Please tell me how to prove this statement.